# Trying to add Update panel in Item template.Getting 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

[image]
Pop-up is created as given in image.

In given image ListView is used. In each row last dropdown depends on the second dropdown, and the second depends on the first. Entire dropdown hierarchy is kept in one Update panel for each row. If I select first dropdown I am able to change second.

Dropdowns in layout template and insert template are kept in Update panel and it's working properly, but if I keep dropdowns in item template in Update panel I am getting 500 error.

Tried code is as follows-

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="UserRoleImage" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            --CheckBox Code--
        </td>
        <td>
            --CheckBox Code--
        </td>
        <td>
            --CheckBox Code--
        </td>
        <asp:updatepanel id="Updatepanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <td style="width:10%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>                                                                                                                         
                </td>      
                <td style="width:10%">                                                                                        
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If I remove Update panel it works fine but on dropdown change my pop-up is getting closed. I want to update only one row of listview of pop-up.

Exact same design is added in layout template and insert template.

Comment: Without the method that throws the error or the actual error message itself there is not much we can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the cause of crash. Since same id of Update panel was using in Item template and Alternate template. I removed Alternate template from list view and Table is rendering perfectly how I was looking for.